# An immediate result of fundamental theorem of algebraic $K$-theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

The fundamental theorem of algebraic $K$-theory says that 
$K_1(R[t,t^{-1}])\cong K_1(R)\oplus K_0(R)\oplus NK_1(R)\oplus NK_1(R)$

On the page 153 of Rosenberg's book on algebraic $K$-theory, he said it follows immediately that $K_0(R)=\text{coker}\{K_1(R[t])\oplus K_1(R[t^{-1}])\longrightarrow K_1(R[t,t^{-1}])\}$.

But this result is not so obvious to me, and I even don't know what the map $K_1(R[t])\oplus K_1(R[t^{-1}])\longrightarrow K_1(R[t,t^{-1}])$ is.

How to prove it?

Comment: K1 is a covariant functor: that map is the sum of the two maps induced by inclusions.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦, so how could this expression of $K_0(R)$ holds?